# Populating a model in Django using loops

Tags: python, django, populate

I'm trying to make a population script that populates a model in a certain way with loops. Here is what the code might look like:

models.py

```
class ExampleModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=128)
```

text.txt

```
001 Name One
    Description one
    Description one line two
023 Name Two
    Description two
    Description two line two
    Description two line three
AAA Name Three
BBB Name Four
    Description three
```

populate.py

```
def populate():
    with open("text.txt") as f:
        content = f.readlines()

    for line in content:
        fields = line.split(' ', 1)
        if len(fields[0]) == 3 and ( fields[0].strip().isupper() or fields[0].strip().isdigit() ):
            code = fields[0].strip()
            name = fields[1].strip()
            print("%s-%s" % (code, name))
            add_object(name=name, code=code)

def add_object(name, code, periship_amount):
    f = ExampleModel.objects.get_or_create(name=name, code=code)[0]
    return f

if __name__ == '__main__':
    populate()
```

Right now, the population script can take any line that starts with a three-character string and divide it into two making the three-character string into the code and the rest of the string into the name. What I want to do is make the entire text (the one's with description in it) below one code-name line and above the other to equal the description field of the code-name above. Does anyone know how to write that loop in the populate.py? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You better use dumpdata and loaddata for poupulations.

With dumpdata you get a file with the data from your db and with loaddata you can load these fixtures into the db.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/initial-data/